# Importing WooCommerce Order Data

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WordPress website that uses WooCommerce as an eCommerce solution. So here's what I'm trying to do:

I want to export all of the orders and order details from an old database to a new one. Pretty simple task right? Well, we're using WooCommerce Product Add-Ons and for some reason, the "Add-Ons" data that was saved to the orders is not showing up on the new database. I've tried importing "Orders" via the WordPress importer, I've tried SQL queries, I've even tried copying the entire wp_posts and wp_postmeta meta tables from the old database to the new one; but nothing is working!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could give this plugin a shot http://www.wpallimport.com/export/

I've used it with great success on several occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Install  and try [this free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/). It's awesome and super simple for [importing and exporting Orders.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-import-export-for-woocommerce/)

They have a quick support as well